# WPF Toolkit - how to refresh a chart

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpftoolkit, dynamics-nav

I just created a pie Chart with the WPF Toolkit. I wanted to create a AddIn for MS Dynamics NAV. If I call that method in NAV:

```
    public void setChart(string chartKey, float chartValue)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, float> value = new KeyValuePair<string, float>(chartKey, chartValue);
        values.Add(value);
    }
```

my Chart is not refreshing. My ObservableCollection is updating but it doesn't Show any Chart. If I just do

```
setChart("AB123",60);
```

to the constructor it works.

How can I update the Chart. I also call `pieChart.DataContext = values;` in the constructor. If I call it again in setChart it still not work.

[Click me: Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGVvJ.png)

Comment: Can I see your `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> values = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your `values` after initializing your windows and since `values` in your example doesn't implement a setter and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` manner, your UI thread is never warn by the change you made on your collection.

Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

Like that when you set your items, Your UI thread knows there is a change to do in the xaml part (I took a Window but it can be a Page, a UserControl or a Custom Class)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> _values;
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> values {
        get {
            if (_values == null) {
                _values = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();
            }
            return _values;
        }
        set {
            _values = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(values)));
        }
    }

....
```

I didn't see your code in your xaml maybe there is a change to do here too.

Comment: Thanks. But I get a Little error while Debugging. `System.NullReferenceException` and ist tell me that "the object reference was not set to an object instance."

Comment: Now it works without any Error. But it didn't solved my Problem. The Code was working and the Problem was set in MS Navision. Problem in NAV: Record.CALCFIELDS(field) was missing. - Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay to sum up:
You Need to use a ObservableCollection<> instead of an List<>.
 The ObservableCollection refreshes automaticly if something changed in it.

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>> values = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();
```

This is mine. The answer above is just the same, just alot longer. Maybe in some situations you Need to use it. But in this case I don't see any use of it. But thanks!
The Problem was Dynamics NAV (I'm using 2016). I wanted to Show Items with its amount. The problem was: The amount was always 0 for some reason. And WPF Toolkit Charts don't Show any tiles with the value 0.
But why it was 0? The amount is a decimal (C/AL) and you Need CALCFIELDS. So I just added `Rec.CALCFIELDS(field);` and it worked! The value was no longer 0! And the Chart Shows me what I wanted.
Maybe I could helped someone with the same Problem :)