# ObservableCollection conditional count

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I think it should be simple but can't believe how to do.

I try bind in label the count of object that have his property `isWorking` set at `True`

Here my collection.

```
public readonly ObservableCollection<ComputerModel.ControleData> _ComputerList =
             new ObservableCollection<ComputerModel.ControleData>();
public ObservableCollection<ComputerModel.ControleData> ComputerList { get { return _ComputerList; } }
```

The result I need in a label is like

```
int workingItems= ComputerList.Where(x=> x.isWorking == true).Count()
```

Then bind in label

```
<Label Content="{Binding workingItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,424,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" Width="62"/>
```

But what is the right method to have this working?? I can't had condition in the WPF itself?

Comment: Do you bind workingItems with DataContext?

Comment: The solution of @S.Akbari is the way to bind `Count` (though I'd put predicate into `Count()` overload and use getter-only property). The only problem still is to get notified when collection is changed to re-evalute value. You can subscribe to `ObservableCollection<T>` [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and just rise notification for new `WorkingItems` property (see `INotifyPropertyChanged`), then your binding will re-evalute it and correct value will be displayed by the view.

Comment: Here an example to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` [I'm here!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42626834/7109040)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a get-only property

```
public int WorkingItems
{
    get { return ComputerList.Where(x=> x.isWorking == true).Count(); }
}
```

Now *you* need to call your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` whenever any `isWorking` property inside the `ComputerList` or the list itself changes.

The following is some pseudo-code to give you an idea what you need to consider in order to notify any possible update. It is **not recommended nor complete** to handle the notifications exactly like this.

```
ComputerList.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => NotifyPropertyChanged("WorkingItems");
this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { if (e.PropertyName == "ComputerList") NotifyPropertyChanged("WorkingItems"); };
foreach (var item in ComputerList)
{
    item.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { if (e.PropertyName == "isWorking") NotifyPropertyChanged("WorkingItems"); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to field but properties. So create a property for `workingItems` and then bind to it:

```
public int WorkingItems
{
    get { return workingItems; }
    set { workingItems = value; }
}

int workingItems= ComputerList.Where(x=> x.isWorking == true).Count();
```

And:

```
<Label Content="{Binding WorkingItems}" .... />
```

Comment: and how you set WorkingItem with the count since collection properties change? i did this at first but the real probleme is seting the value

Comment: @Zwan Just try this with property as I shown. Set `WorkingItem` with the count as before but set the `Content="{Binding WorkingItems}"`. `WorkingItems` is property.

Comment: you totaly ignore collection count in your exemple show  where you set WorkingItems it should be binded to select condition

Comment: @Zwan See my updated answer.

Comment: i gave a pseudo code for condition probleme is not set it once but set WorkingItems rigth when properties in collection change

Comment: the perfect code would be <Label Content="{Binding ComputerList.Where(x=> x.isWorking == true).Count()}" .... /> but it not exist

Comment: @Zwan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842575/why-does-wpf-support-binding-to-properties-of-an-object-but-not-fields